# How to Remove white space in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I am developing a GUI in Java. I have several questions that I am looking to get help with, hope fully some of you can help.

You might need the below image:

[image]

1.. The space between entry's: I want it removed. Right now, each entry is a JPanel with a GridLayout of 2,1. Each row has another JPanel (line1 and line2). By default, line 2 is hidden and should only show when the edit button is clicked, then hide when clicked again. I can change the visibility using setVisible(). But it creates that large space.

*[SOLVED]* 2.. Line2 has a FlowLayout, how can I get it to left align?

3.. Each entry is class (called a "Preset") and is stored in a class variable array called "presetListing". When I click the new branch button, I create a new array with +1 capacity, transfer all the old Presets in and create a new Preset in the last space. What do I need to do to get the new entry to show up in the GUI? I tried adding it to the JPanel and then validate(), didn't work.

Hopefully someoene out there will be able to help me, thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is the code from #3:

```
private void newBranch(){
    Preset[] tempBranches = new Preset[branches.length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < branches.length; i++){
        tempBranches[i] = branches[i];
    }

    tempBranches[branches.length] = new Preset();
    branches = tempBranches;

    pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(branches.length, 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < branches.length; i++){
        pane.add(branches[i]);
    }

    scroller = new JScrollPane(pane);
    this.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.repaint();
    this.validate();
}
```

Comment: #1 I reckon you would need a finer grid. #2 It would probably be best to use a borderlayout-manager instead of a flowmanager. #3 You will need to show us some of your code so we can review it.

Comment: `GridLayout` makes each component the same size. `GridBagLayout` would be more flexible.

Comment: What do you mean by finer grid? Your Solution to #2 worked, Thank you very much! I will find the code now.

Comment: Use a `GridBagLayout` for more control over your form controls, as @kiheru suggests.

Comment: I am looking at GridBagLayout now, I posted the doe that I tried for #3.

Comment: I meant code** in the above comment

Answer (score 0):

That should work to fill the panel with the subpanels:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= _listElements.size(); i++) {
_panel.add(_listElements.get(i), new GridBagConstraints(0, i, 1, 1, 0, 0,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
        new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
}
```